# Categorical reflection of limits and existence of limits

Tags: category-theory

Sorry for my silly question. Suppose that a functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ reflects limits and that $\mathcal{B}$ is a complete category. May I conclude that $\mathcal{A}$ is also complete? More in general, does $\mathcal{A}$ have all the limits existing in $\mathcal{B}$? A similar question for colimits and co-complete categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the following slightly informal definition from [Riehl, p.90]:

"[A functor] $F$ reflects limits if any upstairs cone that maps to a downstairs limit cone is also an upstairs limit cone".

Say $D\colon I \to \mathcal{A}$ is a diagram. Then there is a limit cone on $FD$ given by a natural transformation $\alpha \colon \mathrm{const}_b\to FD$. To get a limit cone of $D$, the only thing you can do is try to lift this cone, i.e. the cone point $b$ along with the arrows of the natural transformation.

In general this fails, for example the Yoneda embedding $y\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}}$ reflects limits  [Riehl, Theorem 3.4.6.], and any functor category to a complete category is complete. The problem is, that you cannot always expect to lift a cone from "downstairs". Dually, $F$ reflecting colimits and $\mathcal{B}$ being cocomplete does not imply that $\mathcal{A}$ is cocomplete.

**Sources:**

Riehl, Emily - "Category theory in context." Courier Dover Publications, 2017.